# htaccess rewrite condition and rewrite rule for redirecting to a page using a particular name having peroids

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have a link  `http://mysite.com/username` which redirects to profile page of current

username..

My htaccess code for this link is :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ profile.php?username=%1 [L,QSA]
```

But my problem is if username conatains periods(.) this condition wont work..

eg: if link is `http://mysite.com/user.name` , it shows not found page..

I want to allow only periods in username, no need of hyphen or underscores...

How can i check it using htaccess?

Someone help me plz....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your RewriteRule code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also keep in mind that underscore is already included by using `\w` in your regex.

Comment: Please be more generous in reporting what's not working? What URI did you try that didn't work?